# Access json nested with react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How are you? I created some more levels in Json that comes from Mongo, however, when accessing elements with more than two levels of nesting, when they can not read the undefined property.

Is there a limitation to how much data can be accessed in a Json? When access by console.log outside of render (), the same, but within the render method, goes two levels even.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share any code, sample input, exception, or expected output.

Comment: no, there is no limit to the "depth" of the data represented in a JSON string. Perhaps you're dealing with asynchrony and don't know it

Comment: use the redux-saga to search the api

Answer (score 0):

I use the redux-saga to search the api:

```
import { all, takeEvery, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from './actions';

const api = 'http://localhost:3003/api/estado/infraestrutura/habitacao';

function* getData() {
  try {
    const data = yield call (
      async () =>
        await fetch(api)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => res)
          .catch(error => error)
    )

    yield put({
      type: actions.INPUT_DATA,
      data
    })
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([takeEvery(actions.GET_DATA, getData)]);
}
```